Create desktop shortcut to open Teams directly to a windowed app
I use the new Teams at work. I have a Planner set up within a team, which I always open in its own window to give it enough space. Is there a way to create a desktop shortcut to open this Planner window directly, rather than having to go through Teams every time?
I can get a direct link to the planner and use that to create an Edge app desktop shortcut, but using this opens it within Teams not its own window.
